# After installing flutter local notification I think i might have done mistake in giving Permission in AndriodManifest.xml file

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-local-notification

My AndriodManifest.xml file code is here

```
manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.clock_app">
   
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
   
   <application
        android:label="clock_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.
            ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.
        ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I Am Getting Errors As Bellow

#FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> G:\clock\clock_app\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:51: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

```
 G:\clock\clock_app\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:57: AAPT: error: unexpected element <receiver> found in <manifest><application><activity>.
```

2

#Please anyone help me to get rid of this errors

Comment: Your "receiver" should outside of activity tag .  Also why are you defining Broadcast Receivers in your code? they are already included in the library code and don't need to be defined again, as far I can see from the documentation.[flutter_local_notifications](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/tree/master/flutter_local_notifications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Move your `<revceiver/>` outside of the `<acivity/>`*

```
    manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.clock_app">
       
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
       
       <application
            android:label="clock_app"
            android:name="${applicationName}"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                     the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                     while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                     to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
                <meta-data
                  android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                  android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                  />
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.
                ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.
            ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
            <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
                 This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                android:value="2" />
        </application>
    </manifest>
```